# Tomcat monitoring MBean Registering

Tags: tomcat, java, jmx, mbeans

I am trying to register Mbeans for Tomcat server monitoring. 
I am using jdk 1.5.

For `HeapMemoryUsage.used` parameter, I am getting the following error:

```
"The observed attribute must be accessible in the observed object." 
 jmx.monitor.error.attribute.
```

If i run the tomcat server on jdk 1.6 version, it is wroking fine.

Answer (score 1):

Monitoring of simple elements inside of complex elements was introduced in Java 1.6.  See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/adoptionguide-137484.html .  As per the comment, here is some more detail.  JMX is the java monitoring framework, in which MBeans are written for the app and are available for reading inside JConsole, which was introduced in JDK5.  The system itself has canned MBeans that provide things like memory used.  In JDK5, MBeans could only return primitives, e.g. numbers or strings.  In JDK6, they could be elements embedded within classes.  The user was trying to get a value within a class: HeapMemoryUsage.used